# Dropbox on both Windows and Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Tags: mount, directory, synchronization, dropbox

I have Dropbox installed on both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS and there are two separate folders that are being synchronized so there is some waste of disk space.
I would like to have only one Dropbox folder to be synchronized and would like to see a link to this particular folder both on Windows and Ubuntu desktops.

The problem is that my original Dropbox folder (the larger and complete one) is on  a separate partition that is not mounted by Ubuntu at startup.
How can I have this partition automatically mounted without me interfering ?

Furthermore, if the Dropbox folder on Ubuntu is deleted will it be reflected to my Dropbox account and the online synchronized files? 
How could this be prevented? I would like to get help on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude directories from synchronization by using the Dropbox CLI.  You add directories to the exclusion list to disable synching and you remove them from the list to re-enable synching.

```
$ dropbox exclude add [DIRECTORY]
```

Partitions that are mounted at system startup are configured by including them in `/etc/fstab` as shown below.  [Here's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) a more detailed explanation that should get you going.

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>    
/dev/sda2       /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
```

Finally, If content is deleted from a synchronized directory the deletion will reflect in Dropbox.  However, Dropbox has a versioning system that can be used to undelete content as well as undo changes.

Comment: I believe selective sync also can be set right from the dropbox software (or at configuring after installation).